# UWP windows store developer dashboard: Rollout Packages

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I am not clear about Gradual package rollout, what is the meaning of 20% rollout? How it applies to new acquisitions? If new user install app form store what will he/she get, newly updated package(which is 20% roll out) or old one? please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document, [Gradual package rollout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/gradual-package-rollout) is for updating packages to a percentage of your app’s customers on Windows 10. All of your customers will see the Store listing details that you entered with your latest submission. The rollout settings only apply to the packages that customers receive, both for new acquisitions and for updates to existing customers.

> what is the meaning of 20% rollout? How it applies to new acquisitions? If new user install app form store what will he/she get, newly updated package(which is 20% roll out) or old one?

20% rollout means that there will be 20% Customers in all your Customers (new and existing customers). That is to say, a customer no matter who is new or old one, he or she will have 20% chance or opportunity to get the newly updated package. So for your question:

> If new user install app form store what will he/she get?

It is hard to say, I can only tell you that it is a probability event, he or she has 20% possibility to get the newly updated package.

Comment: Hi Breeze, thanks for your answer. Is there any way to not letting update to old user, simply use that submission(package) for new installed user only?

Comment: @Aasish Unfortunately, the answer is no, we can not distinguish the user to only make new users install the newly updated package. If you know users's emails, you can use [Package flights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-flights) to distribute specific packages to a limited group of users.